# Shell Date conversion and assign to Variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I have requirement like convert a string date to below format and assign to variable for futher processing.

```
    Input is string as below
    str = 20210709
    Need to get yesterday date and change the format to %Y-%m-%d
    (date -d 'str -1 days' +'%Y-%m-%d')
    and i am expecting output in a variable like below
    dt = 2021-06-09

    I tried like below
    dt =  date -d '20210709 -1 days' +'%Y-%m-%d'
    and the error as below
    -bash: d: command not found
```

Any ideas/Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of things:

- [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax
- no spaces allowed around the `=` for variable assignment

```sh
str=20210709
dt=$(date -d "$str - 1 day" '+%F')
echo "$dt"
```

```sh
2021-07-08
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt=$(paste -d "-" <(echo $str |cut -c1-4) <(echo $str |cut -c5-6) <(echo $str |cut -c7-8))
```

If your version of linux doesn't like that syntax, then

```
dt=$(sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/' <<< $str)
```

Comment: Not working. test.sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 4: `paste -d "-" <(echo $str |cut -c1-4) <(echo $str |cut -c5-6) <(echo $str |cut -c7-8))'

Comment: Must be one of the linux differences.  This will also work: dt=$(sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/' <<< $str) I showed the more complex solution first because it's very easy to read, and many people don't realize how useful the cut and paste commands are

Comment: This also not working sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: What operating system are you using and are you sure your installation isn't corrupted? These commands are legit. The error you got with sed is saying the \3 isn't a valid reference. Since there are three capture groups, I can't see how that would be possible.

Comment: How about calculating yesterday?

Comment: That only requires the extra strip of running it through the date program, e.g dt=$(date -d "$(sed 's/(....)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3/' <<< $str) - 1 day" '+%F') In this case, date can interpret the original string, so Glenn's solution is better. But the sed or cut versions will work when date can't simply read the string -- such as when dates are expressed with the month before the year. Also, using cut, sed, or awk will be way faster if you have a very large number of conversions since you can do them all at once rather than one at a time if you don't have to subtract the day